# How to setup a springboot custom liveness indicator so that a k8s controller can send a liveness probe endpoint to get the overall liveness?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

We have a bunch of services using SpringBoot 2.7.11, all running in k8s containers.  The k8s container has a liveness probe, which is mapped to a bean annotated with `org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint`, with a value of `heartbeat`.  When the k8s controller hits the actuator/heartbeat endpoint on the service, it successfully executes the `heartbeat` method, which has the `@ReadOperation` annotation.  This `heartbeat` method doesn't do more than just set the heartbeat status to `Status.UP` and return. This is all the liveness probe does right now.  We do have more sophisticated readiness indicators, and those apparently work fine and contribute to the overall readiness status.

I'm now trying to implement a custom liveness indicator.  I seem to have half of it working, but not the connection to the endpoint.

I basically have this skeleton:

```
@Component
public class CustomLivenessIndicator extends AbstractHealthIndicator {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Builder builder) throws Exception {
        ...
        builder.down();
    }
}
```

There is conditional logic that checks something and executes `builder.down()` if it doesn't match an expected value.  In my testing, I have it temporarily hacked so that it always calls `builder.down()`.

When I start the service, I see it hit this every 30 seconds or so.

There are two things I don't understand at this point:

- I don't know what to do in our "heartbeat" endpoint method to get the overall liveness summation.
- When I set a breakpoint in my liveness indicator and let it walk back up the stack, I eventually see it return a status of `CORRECT`, as if nothing was wrong.  It seems like the indicator result of `DOWN` is aggregated at some point and seems to be ignored. It's possible I'm just misreading this, and if I knew how to get the overall liveness status in the endpoint, it would show the `DOWN` value.